# How to use parameters in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How is it that the first function works, yet the second one doesn't?

```
<p ng-style="colors.one">1</p>


$scope.turnOn = function()
    {
        $scope.colors.one = {color: "green"};
    }

$scope.turnOff = function(num)
    {
        $scope.colors.num = {color: "red"};
    }

$scope.turnOn();
$scope.turnOff(one);
```

**EDIT**
I tried adding num on $scope.colors like you guys suggested, still can't seem to figure it out.

```
$scope.turnOn = function(num)
    {
        $scope.colors[num] = {color: "green"};
    }

$scope.turnOff = function(num)
    {
        $scope.colors[num] = {color: "red"};
    }
```

I'm calling the functions through

```
<button ng-switch-when='false' ng-click='turnOn(one)'>
<button ng-switch-when='true' ng-click='turnOff(one)'>
```

Comment: Have you tried $scope.colors[num] = {color: "red"}; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i.e because you want to pass string `"one"` and not the value of scope property `one` via ng-click function argument in order to access it as:

```
<p ng-style="colors.one">1</p>
```

i.e

```
<button ng-switch-when='false' ng-click='turnOn("one")'>
<button ng-switch-when='true' ng-click='turnOff("one")'>
```

When you do `ng-click='turnOn(one)'` it is equivalent to calling the function `turnOn` with the value of `$scope.one` which has no value in your case, and using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) will just assign the value to the object, i.e `$scope.colors[num] = ...`

Answer (score 2):

num is not defined on colors. You can access the property num like this.

```
$scope.colors[num] = {color: "red"};
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 'num' has no association to $scope.colors.num

should be

```
$scope.colors[num] = {color: "red"};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to reference variable property names with different notation:

```
$scope.turnOff = function(num) {
    $scope.colors[num] = {color: "red"};
};
```

should work.